# extract points which satisfy certain conditions

Tags: algorithm, geometry, extract, point

I have an array of points in one plane. They form some shape. I need to extract points from this array which only form straight lines of this shape.

At this moment I have an algorithm but it does not work very good. I take first two points, make a straight line and then check if the following points lie on it with some tolerance. But there is a problem: the points which form straight line are not really on the straight but have some deviation. This deviation is quite large. If in my algorithm I make deviation large enough to get points from the straight part, then other points which are on the slightly bent part but have deviation less then specified also extracted.

I am looking for some idea on how to perform such task.

Here is the picture:

[image]

In circles are the parts which I want to extract. Red points are the parts which I could extract with my approach. If I increase the tolerance then I miss the straight pieces too.

Comment: what do you mean by straight lines, exactly? the boundaries?

Comment: A more guiding advise would be to look at `Graham scan` which is a way of computing a convex hull, the idea of the sorting stage might be helpful - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_scan. Good luck.

Comment: @Qnan all the points form some curve, and some parts of this curve are straight pieces. So, I want to extract them.

Comment: @TheNewOne I am looking at this now but I do not see the way of application of the convex hull idea to my problem.

Comment: @AlexPi forget the convex hull, your initial question was misunderstood, I think. The term *shape* is highly ambiguous in this context. I would suggest that you attach a plot of some sample data to show what it actually looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if you already have some candidate subset of points and want to check whether they lie on a straight line. Use a form of [linear regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) to identify the best-fitting line, then check how well it fits and accept or reject the hypothesis that this particular segment is linear based on that.

One of the most standard ways of doing that is using [Least Squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares) method.

Identifying the subset is a different problem, the best solution to which will depend strongly on the kind of data you have and the objective. I suggest that enumerating all the segments is a good starting point, if the amount of data is not extremely large, -- that should be doable in no more than cubic time, I gather.

There are certainly some approximations one can apply, e.g. choosing a point in the sequence and building a subset by iteratively adding points on either side as long as the segment remains linear within the tolerance threshold, than accepting or rejecting it if the segment is long enough.

I assume here that the curve is parameterizable by one of the coordinates. If this is not the case, e.g. if the curve is closed, additional steps may be required to separate the curve into parameterizable segments.

**EDIT: how to check a segment is straight**
There's a number of options.

**First**, I would expect that for a straight line the average deviation would stay roughly the same as you add the new points, then you can simply find a reasonable threshold on that given the data.

**Second** option is to further split the subset into a fixed number of parts (e.g. 2), find the best fitting line for each one and then compare these. In case of a straight line, roughly the same line should be predicted, but for a curve it would be different.

**Third** option is to perform nonlinear curve fitting, e.g. fit a quadratic curve and check the coefficient for the quadratic term -- if the line is straight, it should be close to zero.

In each case, of course, there is a tradeoff between the segment size and the deviation of the points from that segment. In the extreme case, there would either be one huge linear segment with huge deviation or a whole buch of 2-point segments with 0 deviation. The actual threshold on the deviation, the difference between the tangent curves, or the magnitude of the quadratic term (depending on the option you prefer) has to be selected for the given dataset to suit your needs. Looking at the plot, I would say that the threshold should be picked so as to allow for segments of length 10 or so.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I am not familiar with this method and need to study it more deeply. But it may be the solution. Although not very simple...

Comment: @AlexPi the least squares method is actually quite straight forward, but the rest of your problem here may not be so trivial

Comment: the curve is open (if you mean this by "parameterizable"), and the points are in order. So, I can try adding points to the segment and checking if it stays linear. That is what I was actually doing in my first approach.
How would you check if the segment is linear "enough", since the deviation is rather large?